# ionic 2 ion-select not working in ion-card

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 2 in which ion-select is not getting displayed when it is placed inside ion-card. please see my code below :

```
  <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-card>
          <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
          <ion-select>
            <ion-option value="nes">0</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="n64">1</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="ps">2</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="genesis">3</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="saturn">More</ion-option>
          </ion-select>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

If I remove ion-card everything works as expected. Is this a bug in ionic 2 or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `ion-card` component should not go inside of an `ion-item`. As you can see in [this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uYRbfY), you can change it like this to make it work:

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
      <ion-select>
        <ion-option value="nes">0</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="n64">1</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="ps">2</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="genesis">3</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="saturn">More</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Please also notice that I've placed the label and the select elements inside of an `ion-item`.

Answer (score 0):

try card content inside `<ion-card-content></ion-card-content>`

```
<ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-card>
              <ion-label>Quantity</ion-label>
               <ion-card-content>
                <ion-select>
                 <ion-option value="nes">0</ion-option>
                 <ion-option value="n64">1</ion-option>
                 <ion-option value="ps">2</ion-option>
                 <ion-option value="genesis">3</ion-option>
                 <ion-option value="saturn">More</ion-option>
               </ion-select>
            <ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
```